# Microsemi Libero tool version shell command

Tags: libero

Is there any shell script command for getting the libero tool version ? I want that shell script command.

As far as I know, libero tools have get_libero_release command for getting the tool version but this is the tcl command not shell script command.

Can you please help me and tell me what is the shell script command to know the microsemi libero tool version?

For vivado we have below command which can be run from command prompt :-

**Note :- C:\Xilinx\Vivado\2019.2\bin\vivado is the installation directory.**

C:\Users\nnimgaon>**C:\Xilinx\Vivado\2019.2\bin\vivado -version**

**Output :-**

Vivado v2019.2 (64-bit)

SW Build 2708876 on Wed Nov  6 21:40:23 MST 2019

IP Build 2700528 on Thu Nov  7 00:09:20 MST 2019

Copyright 1986-2019 Xilinx, Inc. All Rights Reserved.**

**Do Microsemi Libero tool have such kind of command?**

Comment: If all else fails, run a one-line TCL script from your shell script. Sometimes life's too short to find the right answer.

Comment: Libero does not have such kind of commands. Do not compare Actel and Xilinx. Xilinx has much more built in features as compared to Libero.